Azure Automation Scheduled Jobs Silently Failing
Last week all of the scheduled jobs in one of our Azure Automation Accounts stopped working, then the next day started working again.
When the scheduled jobs stopped working:

there was no error message
the jobs were not started, so no job activity or error messages
jobs failed for both Azure and Hybrid Workers
the Automation Account had nothing significant in the activity history (no changes were made)

While the scheduled jobs were not working, we were able to create a new Azure Automation Account in the same subscription, and were not able to repro the issue.
Waiting to hear back from support.
Curious if others experienced this issue, and what troubleshooting steps were taken.

Could you share the code or script executed so far? @Craig - MSFT

@Jahnavi the issue does not appear to be specific to the runbook host (Azure or Hybrid Worker) or the runbook script (even a script as simple as Write-Host 'foo' does not run).

Checking on it. @Craig - MSFT

There are certain limitations for an Azure automation runbook job to be executed. Check here if this helps. @Craig - MSFT

Hard to tell if any of those limitations were related to the failure.  There were no logs indicating so, it failed silently which was the disturbing part.
